# Hakawai Autoresizing HKWTextView

Tags: ios, swift, tagging, mention

I want to implement LinkedIn's Hakawai mentions in quick adding comment to an item. The problem is the HKWTextView should be as small as possible, fitting it's frame to fit content and suggested mentions list should pop above but I can't find the solution how to achieve this.

I have been trying to autoresize HKWTextView with

```
public func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: newSize.height)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
```

But the results are:

Autoresizing text view:
[image: autoresizing text view]

Started typing mention (list with few mentions):
[image: started typing mention]

List with one mention:
[image: one mention poped]

Without `textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)` method the result is same as on 2nd screen (suggested mention list is invisible showing under table view above)

Have anyone experienced this and managed it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to solve your problem.

1) Create a TextView set fixed Height.

[image: TextView]

2) Select Height Constant and Go to Show the **Size Inspector**.

3) Select Relation as **Greater Than or Equal**.

[image: Set Constant Attribute]

4) Implement this code in your controller file.

```
// Tableview Delegate Method
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotesCell", for: indexPath) as! NotesCell

    cell.txtViewNotes.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.txtViewNotes.delegate = self

    return cell;
}

// Textview Delegate Method
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        adjustFrames(textView)
}

// Custom Method    
func adjustFrames(_ textView: UITextView)  {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: textView.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = yourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! NotesCell

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false);

    self.yourTableView.beginUpdates()
        cell.constNoteHeight.constant = textView.contentSize.height
        textView.beginFloatingCursor(at: CGPoint.zero)
        textView.endFloatingCursor()
    self.yourTableView.endUpdates()

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answet but this textView isn't inside one of cells in tableView, it's in separate view under tableView

Comment: No, You can directly put textView in your tableView. 

1 - Create textView into tableViewCell.

2 - Apply Constraint as per the above example.